# Encryption JSON String

Tags: android

I want to encrypt JSON string and then send it to web server. For encryption I am using AES algorithm.
my JSON string is like :

```
String pJSON = "{\"UserName\":\"abc\",\"Password\":\"123456789\"}";
```

any idea ??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect the password and other personal details whilst they are in transit, it is MUCH better to use HTTPS (secure HTTP) than to do your own encryption because:

- If you do your own encryption/decryption then your app contains everything a hacker needs to decrypt the password, they just need to reverse-engineer it (you can make this harder, but not impossible, using a tool like Proguard)
- HTTPS is designed for this type of scenario, and is much easier to implement. You just buy a secure web server cert (usually less than $100) and install it on the web server.

So I am suggesting that rather than doing your own encryption which is time-consuming and prone to attack, use the existing web infrastructure to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out. I have gone of this encryption just few day before.

```
public class AES_ECB {
    //final static String AES_V1_KEY = "D0QgiY8JYvx8qzKx0iaN8kwEJgwpEqAJ";
     final static String AES_V1_KEY = "BH&625%$#kOhrtxx";
 
    private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/NoPadding";
    // private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CFB/NoPadding";
 
    // private static SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new
    // SecretKeySpec(AES_V1_KEY.getBytes(), "AES");
    // private static byte[] iv = "Htw%$42u&8o*pqxzV#C!33Zq29&bSq2@".getBytes();
    // private static byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5,
    // 0x6,
    // 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF };
    // private static IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
 
    private static final String PROVIDER = "BC";
 
    static String nullPadString(String original) {
        String output = original;
        int remain = output.length() % 16;
        if (remain != 0) {
            remain = 16 - remain;
            for (int i = 0; i < remain; i++)
                output += (char) 0;
        }
        return output;
    }
 
    static String encryptString(final String RAWDATA, boolean ENCODE) {
        String encrypted = null;
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        byte[] key;
 
        key = AES_V1_KEY.getBytes();
        // SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        // Instantiate the cipher
        Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            String input = RAWDATA;
            // KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
            // SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            // sr.setSeed(key);
            // kgen.init(128, sr); //192 and 256 bits may not be available
            // SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            // byte[] raw1 = skey.getEncoded();
 
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, KEY_ALGORITHM);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            // cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,
            // AES_ECB.secretKeySpec,AES_ECB.ivParameterSpec);
            // encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(nullPadString(input).getBytes());
 
            encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(nullPadString(input).getBytes());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
 
        encrypted = new String(encryptedBytes);
        if (ENCODE)
            encrypted = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(encryptedBytes));
        else
            encrypted = new String(encryptedBytes);
        return encrypted;
 
        // /return encrypted;
    }// method end
 
    static String decryptString(final String ENCRYPTEDDATA, final boolean DECODE) {
        String raw = null;
        byte[] rawBytes = null;
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        if (DECODE)
            try {
                encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(ENCRYPTEDDATA.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        else
            encryptedBytes = ENCRYPTEDDATA.getBytes();
        // encryptedBytes = ENCRYPTEDDATA.getBytes();
        byte[] key;
 
        key = AES_V1_KEY.getBytes();
        // SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
 
        Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            // KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
            // SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            // sr.setSeed(key);
            // kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
            // SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            // byte[] raw1 = skey.getEncoded();
 
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, KEY_ALGORITHM);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
 
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            rawBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
 
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        if(rawBytes==null)
             return "";
        else{
         return  raw = new String(rawBytes);
        }
 
//      raw = new String(rawBytes);
//      int delimiter = raw.indexOf('|');
//      int length = Integer.valueOf(raw.substring(0, delimiter));
//      raw = raw.substring(delimiter + 1, length + delimiter + 1);
//      return raw;
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a JSON object.

You can do something like this:

```
    JSONObject JObject=new JSONObject();  
    JObject.put("UserName", "abc");
    JObject.put("Password", "123456789");
```

This will create a similar string then you can send it to server using PUT or POST method.